# Non printable white square in question

Tags: discussion, code-formatting, formatting

See the [revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44255029/revisions) of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44255029/1).

What OP originally posted:

[image]

What we actually got (note the missing squares):

> String a= " 2.8%us, 0.8%sy, 0.1%ni";
>
> //I am using jsch and getting a
> output as mentioned above.How can we replace the box symbols in java?

After many edits attempts, no one could get the square printed.

However, there's another printable ASCII square available (☐) and I replaced the original one with it.

- Is there any way to view the original character OP posted?
- Is this kind of edits acceptable (changing non-printable chars to different, similar but ones)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have downloaded the [source](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1f760cb3-1e2a-40b2-adf3-b167a835a755/view-source) of the original revision and checked with a hex editor, turns out those squares are U+000F "SHIFT IN".

```
$ xxd -g1 view-source 
000000a0: 72 61 70 22 3e 53 74 72 69 6e 67 20 61 3d 20 26  rap">String a= &
000000b0: 71 75 6f 74 3b 0f 0f 20 32 2e 38 25 0f 75 73 2c  quot;.. 2.8%.us,
000000c0: 0f 0f 20 30 2e 38 25 0f 73 79 2c 0f 0f 20 30 2e  .. 0.8%.sy,.. 0.
000000d0: 31 25 0f 6e 69 26 71 75 6f 74 3b 3b 0d 0a 0d 0a  1%.ni&quot;;....
```